# Python pivot point location

Tags: python

How to set pivot point location through python?

for example:

```
object[name].pivot_loc[0] = 0.1
object[name].pivot_loc[1] = 0.5
object[name].pivot_loc[2] = 1
```

I decided to do so...

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
bpy.data.objects[name].select = True
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
```

Comment: Are you talking about a rigid body joint constraint https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/bpy.types.RigidBodyJointConstraint.html?highlight=pivot#bpy.types.RigidBodyJointConstraint.pivot_x

Comment: "For use with the Game Engine" - or not?

Comment: How to access the object through RigidBodyJointConstraint?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to access RigidBodyJoint thru bpy

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
ob = context.active_object

rbjs = [c for c in ob.constraints if c.type == 'RIGID_BODY_JOINT']

for rbj in rbjs:
    print(rbj.name)
    print(rbj.pivot_type)
    print(rbj.show_pivot)
    print(rbj.pivot_x)
    print(rbj.pivot_y)
    print(rbj.pivot_z)
    print()
```

If you know the name you can access directly with

```
rbj = ob.constraints.get('Rigid Body Joint')
```

which will return either the constraint or `None` if there is no constraint with that name.

Comment: Um... Was this accidentally posted on the wrong question? I don't see anything about ridged bodies here...

Comment: Last comment of the OP on question.